# Fast draw wxPython OnPaint

Tags: python, performance, wxpython

I have the following `wx.Window`:

```
class SketchWindow(wx.Window):

  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Window.__init__(self, parent, -1)
    self.SetBackgroundColour('White')
    # Window event binding
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_IDLE, self.OnIdle)
    # run
    self.Run()

  def OnPaint(self, evt):
    self.DrawEntities(wx.PaintDC(self))

  def DrawEntities(self, dc):
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('Black', 1, wx.SOLID))
    dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('Green', wx.SOLID))
    # draw all
    for e in self.entities:
      x, y = e.location
      dc.DrawCircle(x, y, 4)

  def OnIdle(self, event):
    self.Refresh(False)

  def Run(self):
    # update self.entities ...
    # call this method again later
    wx.CallLater(50, self.Run)
```

I need to draw on my window a number of circles [0, 2000] every N milliseconds (50 in my example), where at each step these circles may update their location.

The method I wrote works (the circles are anti-aliased too) but it's quite slow.
Is there a way to improve my solution?

Comment: Why do you need to update so quickly? That's way faster than the eye can see.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Actually if I don't keep the delay so low the animation results very slow (I can't say way). Also on my computer I need 0.005 seconds to update entities and about 0.05 seconds to DrawEntities, therefore 50 milliseconds is the lower bound (I can't go faster...).

Comment: I can't find anything about speed gains for that widget. Drawing 2000 circles every 50 milliseconds sounds pretty extreme though. I don't think anyone will be able to see the drawing taking place at that speed. But you might try floatcanvas (http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.floatcanvas.html) or possibly wxPython's Cairo interface.

Comment: Have you tried using wx.BufferedPaintDC instead of wx.PaintDC?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the Python style is to indent by one tab, or four spaces. Functions and variables should be named in `snake_case`, and classes should be in `PascalCase`. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more style information.

You should also use [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to describe what your functions do. Here's an example of how docstrings are used.

```
def my_func( ... ):
    """
    Describe what your function does and
    it's arguments in this docstring.
    """
    ...
```

Other than that, your code looks pretty nice! Good work!